# QGraphicsTextItem doesn't have methods: setDefaultTextColor and setPos

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am writing first time using Qt, trying to modify Clementine music player and add some useful feature. I almost completed what I wanted to do. But now I need just add text to the window which is `QGraphicsScene`, so I am trying to add text using method: `addText("text")`

It works, but then I need to change color and position of the text in this view.
But Kdevelop doesn't recognize that this `QGraphicsTextItem` (returned by method addText) has methods: `setDefaultTextColor` and `setPos`.

According to documentation it should have.

Qt: 5-15.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was easy. I had to add

```
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
```

and it just works.